# OOP design pattern - add, edit and delete

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Assuming I have to handle the adding, editing or deleting of something.

Is better to create three class like:

```
class AddSomething{}
class DeleteSomething{}
class EditSomething{}
```

or a class with three methods like:

```
class Something{
   public function add(){}
   public function delete(){}
   public function edit(){}
}
```

Another alternative is abstract class, but these three functionality have very little in common, such as add and remove (practically nothing).

What is the best alternative according to the rules of OOP?

Comment: Second approach is better.

Comment: dao pattern, or repository even better

Comment: If you think really deep, this is not so much about OOP design as about system design and crosscutting. I would say, system can be designed in such way that for single table add/edit/delete, you can have one class that can do all your tables. Yes, definitely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Add`, `Edit` and `Delete` would be methods.  `Something` sounds like the subject of the verb, so I would make it an argument to the methods.  What's the object of the verb - who's doing the adding, editing or deleting?  I would represent that actor as a class.

Answer (score 1):

...or three interfaces like: `IAddSomething`, `IEditSomething` and `IDeleteSomething`? Then your classes can choose what roles they take on.